# Button images loaded white?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I set buttons images for normal state and some images is loaded and others appears white.

I need help how to recognize the problem ?

I set the image using the code below

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), forState: .Normal)
```

[image]

Comment: Are those three separate buttons? If so, are you setting the images for each button? Are the buttons in a different state other than normal? Have you tried setting the images for those different states?

Comment: I set the image for each button but in normal state only

Comment: button .setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)

Comment: Image name should be have format, like icon.jpg

Comment: thanks @MuhammadRaheelMateen
button .setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
works but why setImage works for one button and not working for the rest

Comment: I put the image in ImageAsset so image name should not have the format icon.png 
and it already works for one button
@Lee

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change

```
button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), forState: .Normal)
```

to this

```
button .setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
```

Comment: thanks
but why button .setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Normal) works but why setImage works for one button and not working for the rest ?

Comment: please check this also button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)